# Run Time Error Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

Why I'm getting Runtime error in ballerina.

> Error:- "**You must set the JAVA_HOME variable before running Ballerina.**"

[image: Here i attached the screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the JAVA_HOME variable before running the program

To set the JAVA_HOME we use .bash_profile which is a start-up script. This particular file is used for commands which runs when the normal user logs in. The steps to set JAVA_HOME are:

- Login to your account and open .bash_profile file
     $ vi ~/.bash_profile
     If your path is set to /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_06/, set JAVA_HOME as follows:
- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_06/
- Save and close the file. Logout and login back to see new changes, or type source ~/.bashrc

for more http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Java-Home

Answer (score 3):

This might help you.

1) Right click on the My Computer icon on your desktop and select properties

2) Click the Advanced Tab

3) Click the Environment Variables button

4) Under System Variable, click New

5) Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME

6) Enter the variable value as the install path "C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06" (**Assuming your jdk path is in this directory**)

7) Click OK

8) Click Apply Changes

9) Restart the computer to make sure the changes are reflected.

10) Voila! ;)

Comment: You don't have to restart the computer. Just close and restart the command prompt, it will work. (Not sure about earlier versions, it works in Win 10)

Answer (score 2):

1. Locate the Java installation directory (if you did not change the directory when the installation,it'll be something like this.  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65`)
2. Windows 8 or 10 – Go to **Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings**
3. Click the **Environment Variables**
4. Under System Variables, click **New**
5. In the Variable Name field, enter either: `JAVA_HOME` if you installed the `JDK` (Java Development Kit) or `JRE_HOME` if you installed the `JRE` (Java Runtime Environment)
6. In the Variable Value field, enter your `JDK` or `JRE` installation path

[image]

7. Click **OK**

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the [Ballerina windows installer](https://ballerina.io/downloads/) instead of extracting the distribution from the zip file, as the installer contains a bundled JRE(1.8) so that the users won't have to worry about their local java environment.